# Does ISIS claim that every Muslim who doesn't give bayah to Baghdadi is an apostate/infidel?

Tags: isis

[PragerU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prager_University) is a Conservative/Libertarian web-site. In one of their videos, *[What Isis Wants](https://youtu.be/v7f0bKIOwys?t=3m)*, [Tom Joscelyn](http://www.defenddemocracy.org/about-fdd/team-overview/thomas-joscelyn/) says:

> ISIS claims that any Muslim who does not swear bay'ah (an oath of allegiance) to Baghdadi is an "infidel" or an "apostate".

<sup>*[Baghdadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr_al-Baghdadi) is the leader of ISIL.*</sup>

Is that true?

Comment: Why is this surprising? Plenty of extremist organisations would claim that anyone who doesn't support them is a traitor.

Comment: Is surprise a requirement?

Comment: @DJClayworth I posted this because I couldn't find any evidence for it.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the article ["What ISIS Really Wants"](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2015/03/what-isis-really-wants/384980/) by Graeme Wood, ISIS supporters see Baghdadi as a legitimate caliph. This is a defining feature of ISIS. Muslims in general recognize that bay'ah to a legitimate caliph would be a fundamental duty. But only ISIS supporters (not even Al-Qaeda) believe that any legitimate caliphate has existed since (at least) the fall of the Ottoman sultanate.

According to Wood, referring to a particular sermon by Baghdadi:

> the caliph commands obedience—and those who persist in supporting
>   non-Muslim governments, after being duly warned and educated about
>   their sin, are considered **apostates**.

Wood quotes directly from Baghdadi's sermon as follows, in reference to supporting the calpihate:

> This is **a duty upon the Muslims**—a duty that has been lost for
>   centuries … The Muslims **sin** by losing it, and they must always seek to
>   establish it.

Note that in [the available translation of the sermon itself](https://news.siteintelgroup.com/Jihadist-News/abu-bakr-al-baghdadi-appears-in-video-delivers-sermon-in-mosul.html) the specific language of "infidels" or "apostates" is not used directly by Baghdadi himself, but arguably implied.

EDIT:
ISIS directly discusses "apostasy" in various statements included as an appendix [a Brookings report](https://www.brookings.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-ideology-of-the-Islamic-State.pdf). In these statements they explicitly label the following groups as apostate: "[t]hose worshiping—or perceived to be worshiping—stones, saints, tombs, etc.", Shia muslims, "sorcerers", "whoever participates in the political process", "whoever  extends  to  the  occupier  and  his  supporters  any  kind  of  assistance", "whoever  disparages  [the] honored  stature  and  position [of the Prophet or the Rightly Guided Caliphs]", "all the rulers and armies of these states [of unbelief]", etc.

This falls short of literally labeling *all* Muslim non-supporters as apostates, but it comes fairly close because it is so open-ended. The only explicit limit they place is where they say "we do not believe in the unbelief of the  generality of those entering [the political process], so long as legal proof has not [yet] been furnished for them."

Comment: Does the article by Wood claim that if a caliphate exists it's a muslim's duty to support it? If so, please cite the relevant part, if not, please cite a source that does claim it.

Comment: @SIMEL It does and I did, but I also just added the exact quote from Baghdadi that Wood uses.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Here is a video of Baghdadi's sermon: http://sitemultimedia.org/video/SITE_IS_Baghdadi_Sermon_Mosul.mp4 If you feel the translation above is biased or warrants a different interpretation, then by all means provide a better one.

Comment: "This is a duty upon the Muslims—a duty that has been lost for centuries … The Muslims sin by losing it, and they must always seek to establish it." --

This in no way means that ISIS is claiming all those who don't follow him are apostates. 

"In return, the caliph commands obedience—and those who persist in supporting non-Muslim governments, after being duly warned and educated about their sin, are considered apostates." -- That sounds more like his speculation than something  real.

Comment: I've added more quotes from ISIS itself.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin I think it is pretty clear by now that ISIS don't treat extremists muslims aligned with it as real muslims.